# I am a beginner and need your advice

Tags: google-sheets

I'm creating a webpage which can show the attendance of the student.
I connected my google sheet and it was okay to fetch the data from the goole sheet.
However, it was not possible to fetch the updated data (checked in and out of each student) to the google sheet and make the check in and out columns of each student to be automatically updated in the google sheet.

I tried to use API key but it is working for fetching from the google sheet not fetching to google sheet.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Student Attendance Tracker</title>
<style>
    body {
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    }
    #output {
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Student Attendance Tracker</h1>
    <label for="barcodeInput">Scan Barcode:</label>
    <input type="text" id="barcodeInput" autofocus>
    <div id="output"></div>

    <script>
        // Function to update Google Sheet with check-in/check-out data
        function updateGoogleSheet(student) {
            const sheetId = '107mxmA8o7YDK6Q8-2Pmyhb6wZSH5QSyw-4nUll9D-Tw'; // Replace with your Google Sheet ID
            const apiKey = 'AIzaSyDMjgczWfQqDlewBSE-fHC-lPNSxKoOFnA'; // Replace with your Google API Key
            const range = `Sheet1!A:F`; // Update range as needed

            const updateUrl = `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${sheetId}/values/${range}:append?valueInputOption=RAW&key=${apiKey}`;

            const updatePayload = {
                range: 'Sheet1',
                majorDimension: 'ROWS',
                values: [[student.id, student.name, student.address, student.gender, student.checkIn, student.checkOut]]
            };

            fetch(updateUrl, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(updatePayload),
            })
            .then(response => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error('Failed to update Google Sheet');
                }
                console.log('Google Sheet updated successfully');
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error updating Google Sheet:', error);
            });
        }

        // Function to find student by ID
        function findStudentById(studentId, studentData) {
            return studentData.find(student => student.id === studentId);
        }

        // Function to display student information
        function displayStudentInfo(student) {
            const outputDiv = document.getElementById('output');
            let attendanceInfo = '';

            const options = { 
                hour: 'numeric', 
                minute: 'numeric', 
                second: 'numeric', 
                month: 'long', 
                day: 'numeric', 
                year: 'numeric' 
            };

            if (student.checkIn && student.checkOut) {
                attendanceInfo = `Checked In: ${new Date(student.checkIn).toLocaleString('en-US', options)}<br>Checked Out: ${new Date(student.checkOut).toLocaleString('en-US', options)}`;
            } else if (student.checkIn) {
                attendanceInfo = `Checked In: ${new Date(student.checkIn).toLocaleString('en-US', options)}<br>Checked Out: Not Yet`;
            } else {
                attendanceInfo = `Checked In: Not Yet<br>Checked Out: Not Yet`;
            }

            outputDiv.innerHTML = `
                <h2>Student Information</h2>
                <p><strong>Name:</strong> ${student.name}</p>
                <p><strong>Address:</strong> ${student.address}</p>
                <p><strong>Gender:</strong> ${student.gender}</p>
                <p><strong>Attendance:</strong></p>
                <p>${attendanceInfo}</p>
            `;
        }

        // Function to initialize attendance tracking with fetched data
        function initializeAttendanceTracking(studentData) {
            document.getElementById('barcodeInput').addEventListener('change', function() {
                const scannedId = this.value.trim();
                const student = findStudentById(scannedId, studentData);
                if (student) {
                    const currentTime = new Date().toLocaleString();
                    const isCheckIn = !student.checkIn || student.checkOut;
                    if (isCheckIn) {
                        student.checkIn = currentTime;
                    } else {
                        student.checkOut = currentTime;
                    }
                    updateGoogleSheet(student);
                    displayStudentInfo(student);
                } else {
                    alert('Student not found. Please try again.');
                }
                this.value = ''; // Clear input field after scanning
            });
        }

        // Function to fetch data from Google Sheet
        function fetchDataFromGoogleSheet() {
            const sheetId = '107mxmA8o7YDK6Q8-2Pmyhb6wZSH5QSyw-4nUll9D-Tw'; // Replace with your Google Sheet ID
            const apiKey = 'AIzaSyDMjgczWfQqDlewBSE-fHC-lPNSxKoOFnA'; // Replace with your Google API Key
            const range = 'Sheet1!A:F'; // Update range as needed

            const url = `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${sheetId}/values/${range}?key=${apiKey}`;

            console.log('Fetching data from Google Sheet...');
            fetch(url)
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    console.log('Data fetched successfully:', data);
                    const studentData = data.values.map(column => ({
                        id: column[0],
                        name: column[1],
                        address: column[2],
                        gender: column[3],
                        checkIn: column[4],
                        checkOut: column[5]
                    }));

                    initializeAttendanceTracking(studentData);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error('Error fetching data from Google Sheet:', error);
                });
        }

        // Call the function to fetch data from Google Sheet and initialize attendance tracking
        fetchDataFromGoogleSheet();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: "not fetching to google sheet" - what does that mean? What have you tried to resolve the problem? Also, please adjust the tagging of your question

Comment: This is the error.

QR Code.html:37 
        
        
       POST https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/107mxmA8o7YDK6Q8-2Pmyhb6wZSH5QSyw-4nUll9D-Tw/values/Sheet1!A:F:append?valueInputOption=RAW&key=AIzaSyDMjgczWfQqDlewBSE-fHC-lPNSxKoOFnA 401 (Unauthorized)
updateGoogleSheet @ QR Code.html:37
(anonymous) @ QR Code.html:105
QR Code.html:51 Error updating Google Sheet: Error: Failed to update Google Sheet
    at QR Code.html:46:27

Comment: Please add all clarification **to your question** by editing. it